# matrix-bot-sdk on docker node:alpine

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I have an issue with docker image size which is hard to resolve. Running a [146M package](https://github.com/wencai-chinese/translator-bot.git), it takes a 1.34GB container (matrix-bot) for the image to work properly.

```
REPOSITORY                              TAG               IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
translator-bot-zh                       v1.0              156d9b3ba89c   4 minutes ago    385MB
matrix-bot                              latest            9939ff6eb899   11 hours ago     1.34GB
```

Though I can build a `node:alpine` image that is 385MB, I keep running into dependency and other issues.

```js
sudo docker run --platform linux/x86_64 --rm -it translator-bot-zh:v1.0
5f75e9cc0768:/app# npm start

> bot@1.0.0 start
> node dist/basic-bot.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1472
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Error relocating /app/node_modules/matrix-bot-sdk/node_modules/@matrix-org/matrix-sdk-crypto-nodejs/matrix-sdk-crypto.linux-x64-musl.node: __register_atfork: symbol not found
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1472:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1234:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/matrix-bot-sdk/node_modules/@matrix-org/matrix-sdk-crypto-nodejs/index.js:175:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1375:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1434:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v21.5.0
```

```bash
sudo docker build -t translator-bot-zh:alpine .
[+] Building 564.2s (14/14) FINISHED                                                                                               docker:default

 => ERROR [10/10] RUN npm start                                                                                                              7.4s
------
 > [10/10] RUN npm start:
3.471 
3.471 > bot@1.0.0 start
3.471 > node dist/basic-bot.js
3.471 
6.832 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473
6.832   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
6.832                  ^
6.832 
6.832 Error: Error relocating /app/node_modules/matrix-bot-sdk/node_modules/@matrix-org/matrix-sdk-crypto-nodejs/matrix-sdk-crypto.linux-x64-musl.node: __register_atfork: symbol not found
6.832     at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473:18)
6.832     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
6.832     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
6.832     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
6.832     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
6.832     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/matrix-bot-sdk/node_modules/@matrix-org/matrix-sdk-crypto-nodejs/index.js:175:31)
6.832     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
6.832     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
6.832     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
6.832     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) {
6.832   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
6.832 }
6.834 
6.834 Node.js v20.11.0
------
Dockerfile:26
--------------------
  24 |     
  25 |     # Run Appp
  26 | >>> RUN npm start
  27 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm start" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

## Question

How do we get matrix-bot-SDK running on an alpine container without these errors?

**Dockerfile**：

```bash
# Build stage
FROM node:20-alpine

# Install bash and other libraries
RUN apk --update --no-cache add bash
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk add --no-cache musl
RUN apk add gcompat

# Set bash as the default shell
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy only the package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY . . 

# Install dependencies and remove unnecessary files in a single layer
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

# Build App
RUN npm run build

# Run Appp
RUN npm start
```

**package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "node dist/basic-bot.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Sati",
  "license": "ISC",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/translate": "latest",
    "@matrix-org/matrix-sdk-crypto-nodejs": "latest",
    "axios": "latest",
    "dotenv": "latest",
    "esm": "latest",
    "franc": "latest",
    "htmlencode": "latest",
    "lru-cache": "latest",
    "matrix-bot-sdk": "latest",
    "matrix-js-sdk": "latest",
    "uuid": "latest",
    "typescript": "latest",
    "vorpal": "latest",
    "@types/express": "latest",
    "another-json": "latest",
    "async-lock": "latest",
    "chalk": "latest",
    "express": "latest",
    "glob-to-regexp": "latest",
    "hash.js": "latest",
    "html-to-text": "latest",
    "lowdb": "latest",
    "mkdirp": "latest",
    "morgan": "latest",
    "postgres": "latest",
    "request": "latest",
    "request-promise": "latest",
    "sanitize-html": "latest"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/google-translate-api": "latest",
    "@babel/core": "latest",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "latest",
    "@babel/eslint-plugin": "latest",
    "@testcontainers/postgresql": "latest",
    "@types/async-lock": "latest",
    "@types/jest": "latest",
    "@types/lowdb": "latest",
    "ts-mocha": "latest",
    "@types/node": "latest",
    "@types/sanitize-html": "latest",
    "@types/simple-mock": "latest",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "latest",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "latest",
    "better-docs": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-google": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-matrix-org": "latest",
    "get-port": "latest",
    "jest": "latest",
    "jsdoc": "latest",
    "matrix-mock-request": "latest",
    "simple-mock": "latest",
    "taffydb": "latest",
    "testcontainers": "latest",
    "tmp": "latest",
    "ts-jest": "latest",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```